# mysql thread stuck 'cleaning up' with locked rows

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm getting an error that states:
Error: ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Then on pulling INNODB status i find the following transaction. Why would this be stuck in cleaning up for such a long duration?

The code stack is node.js using express server on mysql.

---TRANSACTION 656166535, ACTIVE 79651 sec
52 lock struct(s), heap size 5296, 86 row lock(s), undo log entries 200
MySQL thread id 101761, OS thread handle 0x639c, query id 71887219 localhost 127.0.0.1 root cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 656242192, sees < 656242192